# if a lot of pcap handler is created in a program, is libpcap resource consuming or efficient?

Tags: pcap, libpcap, tcpdump

I have a program which may create a lot of pcap handlers
each of which uses different capture filter

I'm afraid they are very resource consuming and so the program/machine may not support them
are there any insights in this regard?
thanks!